# Does saveInBackground or saveEventually return the object saved in the callback?

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

I have a simple question and there was nothing in the document so I'm asking here. When you save an object, on the callback, is the saved object returned from the server?

Comment: Please don't offer voting advice in posts - it is not of interest to most readers. We also ask that posts are written in succinct, technical writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes the updated object is returned from the server

Answer (score 1):

[From the Android Documentation](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/):

> ```
> myObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
>    public void done(ParseException e) {
>      if (e == null) {
>        myObjectSavedSuccessfully();
>      } else {
>        myObjectSaveDidNotSucceed();
>      }
>    }
>  });
> ```

So no, the callback does not contain the saved object, which is fine because in order to call `save` on an object, you must already have a reference to it.

The callback only returns an exception if there was an error saving the object.

Comment: You were wrong,save returns the Lastest Parse Object.
I made a change in a variable in the server , and then in the local instance i made a change to a different field.
After I saved the object, my local instance contained the changes made both locally and on the server